# Alternatives to many parent() in selection

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of code that I keep doing in some apps

```
var current = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('data-panel'));
```

Moving into the children I can use .find(). Is there anything like that that works backwords rather than me having so many parent() functions>

Comment: closest() - For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

Answer (score 5):

```
$(this).closest('[data-panel]').attr('data-panel');
```

Will traverse 'up' through the ancestors of the `$(this)`/`this`, and select the first element with a `data-panel` attribute.

References:

- [Has-attribute (`[attribute]`) selector](http://api.jQuery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jQuery.com/closest/).

Comment: Super! Thats bang on what I needed!

Thanks for the fast response :)

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility:

```
$(this).parents().eq(3).attr('data-panel')
```

Comment: This will work, but I'd recommend against it, as it ties your script logic to a very specific HTML structure. This will break if the number of parents ever changes.

Comment: @BrandonGano Totally agree, i was gonna post the same answer as David, but he did it first, so instead of posting a duplicate, I gave an alternative in case someone in the futur doesn't have that attribute.